# Is it possible to delete files older than x days in a sharepoint folder using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am looking to run a script nightly to delete zip files older than 7 days. In Documents I have a folder called folder1 and inside that folder there are subfolders containing zip files. I have seen examples for sites/lists but not folders. The following cold will return:

But I would like to recursively delete all zip files in folder1 that are over 7 days old.

```
Try {
   #Setup the context
   $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $SPOnlinePassword -AsPlainText -Force
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
   $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($SPOnlineUserName, $securePassword)

   #Get the List
   $List = $Context.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

   #Define CAML Query to Filter
   $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
   $Query.ViewXML = "<View Scope=RecursiveAll>
                        <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <And>
                                    <Contains>
                                        <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>.zip</Value>
                                    </Contains>
                                    <Leq>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Created' Type='DateTime'/>
                                        <Value Type='DateTime'>
                                            <Today OffsetDays='-7'/>
                                        </Value>
                                    </Leq>
                                </And>
                            </Where>
                        </Query>
                    </View>"

   #Get List Items
   $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
   $Context.Load($ListItems)
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()

   Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$ListItems.Count
   write-host $ListItems.Name
   #Get Each Item's Created Date
   $ListItems | ForEach-Object { Write-host ("List Item:{0} was created on {1}" -f $_["FileLeafRef"], $_["Created"]) }

   foreach ($item in $ListItems) {
      $List.getItemById($item.id).deleteObject()
   }
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
Catch {
   write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Edit: I have the above code sort of working until I received 'Error: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use the below PowerShell script.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
cls



$fileName = "File_Deleting_Report"
#'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
#$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName 

$isLogFileCreated = $False 



#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL

        } 

#DLL location

$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


#File Download location

$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Downloaded Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#File Download location



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 




#Parameters
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/"
$listName="Documents"
$fromDate="2019-12-08"
$toDate="2019-12-12"
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation;
$userName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "YourSPOPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$batchSize =1000

#Parameters ends here.


#Setup the Context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)

  <#
  $web = $ctx.Web
  $ctx.Load($web)
  $ctx.Load($web.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()#>



  #The below code is for root site

$docLibraryColl=$ctx.Web.Lists
$ctx.Load($docLibraryColl)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($oneList in $docLibraryColl)
{

if($oneList.BaseTemplate -eq "101" -and $oneList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $oneList.Hidden -eq $False -and $oneList.IsCatalog -eq $False -and $oneList.IsApplicationList -eq $False) 
{



#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($oneList.Title)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$emptyString = ""
#Define CAML Query to get Files from the list in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery


$startDateVar=$fromDate+"T13:35:58Z"
#$startDate=Get-Date -Date $startDateVar; 
$endDateVar=$toDate+"T13:36:34Z"
#$endDate=Get-Date -Date $endDateVar;



$Query.ViewXml = "@
    <View Scope='Recursive'>
        <Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$startDateVar</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$endDateVar</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>        
    </View>"



$count =0

#Get List Items in Batches
Do
{


    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $ListItems.Count

    #Update Postion of the ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition

    If ($ListItems.Count -eq 0) { Break }

    $fileCount=1;

    #Update List Item
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {                    


            try
            {

              $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

              $Item.File.DeleteObject();
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()              


             Write-Host $Item.File.Name "has been deleted successfully" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen




        }
        catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +$file.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }       



    }
    Write-Host "============================================================="
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host "============================================================="

}While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

}


}
```

**Notes:**

- In the above script you can pass from date to date as parameters those files will be deleted. Or in the camel query you can extract the data greater than X date.
- Inside for each loop, using the **$Item.File** property you can check the zip file type before deleting or even you can add this in the camel query itself.
- This is tested in SharePoint online but it will work in SharePoint On-Premise as well, as this is developed in client object model.

For details details refer to the below article :

[SharePoint Online: Delete All Files from document library for the given date – PowerShell CSOM](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/powershell/sharepoint-online-delete-all-files-from-sharepoint-online-site-from-a-given-date/amp/)